# How to search for the pattern in python using re package?

Tags: python, regex

I've a file say with following contents:

```
hello//hello1
this is a file
good-morning
```

I want to check for a pattern that begins and ends with double quotes and has `//` character in between the quotes as shown in the above string. Output should be :

```
hello//hello1
```

Comment: The result of a search is match object, not your string output. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
>>> my_string
'"hello//hello1" this is a file "good-morning"'
>>> re.findall('"\w+//\w+"', my_string)
['"hello//hello1"']
```

Comment: In demo I have shown, its working perfectly. Can you show how you trying

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `findall`

```
>>>re.findall('"\w+//\w+"','mystring "hello//hello1" sample')
['"hello//hello1"']
```